# Stale element reference from Selenium on code that was already executed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

while trying to scrap some infos on live nba games I encounter a stale reference, nothing particular yet since it is my first scrapping project but it looks pretty complex though, like the error could come from code previously executed.

Some context will help first : I want to scrap multiple games simultaneously using Python3, Selenium and undetected_chromedriver, for this reason I iterate through my list of games and for each game I do the following actions.

- Open a driver
- Get the website
- Find NBA games ("competition" in the code)
- Iterate through games (game_web_element)
- If home team of game in List matches home team of game_web_element click() to go on game's webpage to scrap

Now the problem : it don't work... more specifically, it works a first time the page of the first game loads telling me I reached at least the game_web_element.click() line, but..

[Stale element reference exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQpCR.png)

[The code of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mju1v.png)

I did multiple tries after to see if the problem came from the second loop, when I scrap the second game but it doesn't seem so, it looks like the error comes from the fact that the element team2.text is no longer available because the code resulting from the condition is already executed which makes no sense.

Unfortunately i didn't screenshot the other tries with "print(team2.text)" inserted before "teams2.append(team2.text)" which gave more info, i must have been too tired, i'll give more info tonight if it helps.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: once you click the "game_web_elements" array will go stale.  (so you can't do that while iterating over the elements)

Comment: Yes indeed, i was not clear enough, i iterate through array 1 which are the games I want to scrap. For each of these games I do the whole process from creating a driver to the click(), after this click() i have no reference to any element of the page. Then i end the loop by dumping the content of the page the driver is on and repeat the process for next game of array 1.

Comment: Yes, once you click the DOM is updating and you need to re-grab all arrays.  Don't click or do any actions that make changes to the DOM while iterating through webelement reference arrays.  (those references will go stale)

Comment: Ooooh I didn’t realise that I would  continue to iterate through games_web_element, I’ m definitely too tired. I don’t see how I can achieve this though. Should I break out of the for loops if it is possible or should I store the WebElement I want too click to do it after the loops are done and before opening the file (Maybe using a global var, I dont seem to be able to initialise an empty WebElement at the beginning of the function) ?

Comment: I didn't look too close... it might be the array above that... they'll all go stale once the dom updates.